# С++, консольный толковый словарь, поиск слова и его значения по букве

Tags: c++, файлы, поиск, словарь

У меня есть текстовый файл со словами и их определениями, так же в файле присутствует точка с запятой, разделяющяя слово и значение и разное количество пробелов между ними. Каждое слово с определением в новой строке. Это выглядит так:

> apple; edible fruit produced by an apple tree

> dog;common animal with four legs, especially kept by people as a pet or to hunt or guard

> light; the natural agent that stimulates sight and makes things visible

Мне нужно задать тип, как я хочу искать слово: по первой букве, по любой букве из слова или по последней букве.  Затем поместите это слово на экран с его определением в формате типа «слово - определение» (если есть другие слова, начинающиеся с той же буквы, поместить таковые все)
У меня есть код, но я не знаю как правильно читать из файла, а затем искать по буквам.  Спасибо за вашу помощь.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream input;
    input.open("dictionary.txt"); 

    if(!input.is_open()){
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    } 

    else{
        char ch;
        string str; 

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                cout << "Reading file";
                cout << " " << i << endl;
                sleep(0);
                system("cls");
        } 

        cout << "File was open" << endl;
        sleep(0);
        cout.flush();
        system("cls"); 

        int choise;
        
        menu:
        cout << "1. Starting\n2. Containing\n3. Ending\n4. Stop\nInput your choise: ";
        cin >> choise;
        system("cls"); 

        switch(choise){
            case 1:{   // searching by 1 letter
                cout << "Input letter: ";
                goto menu;
            } 

            case 2:{  // searching by any letter in word
                goto menu;
            } 

            case 3:{  // searching by last letter 
                 goto menu;
            } 

            case 4:{
                system("cls");
                cout << "Closing file" << endl;
                sleep(2);
                break;
            } 

            default:{
                cout << "Input 1-4!" << endl;
                goto menu;
            }
        }
    } 

    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Ну то есть из условия вы ничего не реализовали? Даже если не правильно. То есть приведенный вами код даже не является попыткой по факту. Не пробовали в гугле вбить "как читать из файла c++"?? А поиск по букве это вообще элементарно. 2 проверки и 1 цикл нужен, чтобы все 3 варианта поиска реализовать.

Comment: Как раз таки считывать, я считывал, но в одном случае я не знаю как избавиться от точки с запятой, а во втором от пробелов. То есть создать некие 2 группы первая слово, а вторая - значение. Не говоря о том как искать по буквам в начале слова, в конце ...

Comment: Приведите код, где вы пытаетесь считать из файла строку. Потом подсказка при помощи например функции `strtok` разделяете считанную строку по `;`. И далее вам просто немного подумать нужно. У вас есть символ введенный и вам нужно найти слово например по 1 букве, и не ужели никаких мыслей нет?? Подсказка проще некуда. Сравнить введенную букву и первую букву слова

Comment: Понимаю теперь, благодарю

Comment: strtok не нужен. Тем более, в связке с string. Если допустить, что пользователь не вводит точку с запятой как часть строки, то весь код сводится к while(..getline(..)) {проверка, что строка пользователя в начале такая же как и получена, вывод}

Comment: @KoVadim что мешает использовать си строку? И я конечно не автор вопроса, но разве по условию слово не разделено ; от значения слова, просто как понять "не вводит точку с запятой". И причем тут проверка строк, если поиск по букве.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков то, что это C++ и чтобы использовать в нём сишную строку и её функции нужны веские причины.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков господи опять вы... То есть вы за то, что если код на c++, то всегда использовать string. А к массиву символов вообще не прикасаться?? Не согласен и даже спорить не буду на эту тему.

Comment: не стоит использовать массив символов, если Вам просто так хочется. Сколько заводить символов? 100? 200? 1000? выделять динамически? А со string все просто - будет автоматом.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков мне считывать в массив через while(file.get(ch)) или же через while(!file.eof())?

Comment: @KoVadim ну а зачем мне целый класс string если по факту нужна сама строка и  функция разделения. Да она даже и не нужна. Циклом пройтись найти первое вхождение ; и заменить его на -, а то что слева по одному из способов разобрать. strtok для упрощения привел. А строку можно статичным размером взять и этого будет достаточно. 1000 символов с головой хватит, чтобы описать любое слово.

Comment: @Assaraid если используете string, то лучше построчно считывать. `while(getline(file, str))`

Comment: 1000 символов хватит. И вот так потом находятся баги. Расскажите это любому QA, посмотрите на его реакцию:)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков да в C++ всегда должен быть string, пока нет убедительных доводов заюзать что-либо иное. не нравится string, так есть ещё string_view и span да и в boost ещё. И в правильном коде строка появляется сразу в string. А getline(file, str) это ооочень медленный способ считывать файлы.

Comment: @KoVadim вообще можно хранить в динамическом массиве лишь само слово. А это ну символов 100. (Если конечно самое длинное слово кто-то не захочет записать в файл). Если слово подходит под проверку, то сразу из файла и выводить в консоль его значение.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков xd как вы любите комментарии по типу "это ооочень медленный способ считывать файлы." писать, никогда не обходите стороной момент, где можно показать свои знания и автор вроде не стремиться за скоростью.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков и как вы предлагаете считывать данные?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков если автору не нужна скорость, то лучше вообще взять C#, есть овер дофига топовых игр и приложений на нём.

Comment: @Assaraid например так: string GetFileText(const filesystem::path& path)
{
 ifstream f(path);
 return string(istreambuf_iterator<char>(f), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}